# Pillow PixelAccess TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to loop over some pixels and edit them with `PixelAccess`. For some reason, when I try to set the pixels, Python gives me `TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)`

```
pixels[(x, y)] = pix
```

is the exact code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gen_shuttletiles.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "./gen_shuttletiles.py", line 76, in main
    pixels[(x, y)] = pix
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

`pix` is a 4-tuple of numbers for the RGBA values of the image.
I tried to change the amount of numbers of items in the tuple by adding some zeroes, and the count given in the error does go up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, the image was on mode `P` so I had to convert it to `RGBA` beforehand.

Comment: I know, but Stack overflow requires you to wait 2 days before you can self accept answers.

Thanks for reminding me though!